# Is it "that" or "how"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I have been thinking about a title for a post on another website that I'd made all day. At first, I had worded it like, "Reasons That [character one's name here] and [character two's name here] Are Similar", but I started thinking about it, and I thought that maybe "Reasons How" would be best here?

I'm not sure... Can someone help me and explain to me which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: After _reasons_, it's _why_.

Comment: You don't need either --->  'Reasons John and Mary Are Similar'

Comment: I like "Why John and Mary Are Similar"

Answer (score 1):

The correct version would be to use "that." "How" is an adverb, as opposed to the relative clause "that" serves in your title. You could switch "why" in for "that." Leaving a clause out entirely is also an option, to just have "Reasons [Bilbo] and [Frodo] Are Similar," for example.

Comment: Thank you! It's been bugging me since yesterday because neither one seemed to sit well with me after I'd thought, "Well, maybe it's 'How'..."

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the question - *Why* explains reason.
So, it should be:

> *Reasons **why** A and B are similar*

As it is a title for your post, you don't need to use a clause as @chasly from UK has mentioned

> *Reasons A and B are similar*